# ValueError: rate must be a scalar tensor or a float in the range [0, 1), got 1

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a classification model using Keras in a Colab notebook but the problem is that when I try to fit my augmented model it stops in the validation steps showing the error:

ValueError: rate must be a scalar tensor or a float in the range [0, 1), got 1

I have been searching on the web but I can not find this error.The code is the next:

```
batch_size = 10
img_height= 180
enter code here
img_width = 180
nb_test_samples = 400
nb_val_samples = 200
epochs = 10
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
valid_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/content/validacion/',
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')
input_shape = (180,180,3)
model =  Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),input_shape = input_shape,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=((2,2))))
model.add(Conv2D(63,(3,3),activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=((2,2))))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(1))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer='rmsprop',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

train_datagen_augmented = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,        
    shear_range=0.2,       
    zoom_range=0.2,        
    rotation_range = 30,
    horizontal_flip=True) 

train_generator_augmented = train_datagen_augmented.flow_from_directory(
    '/content/entrenamiento',
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator_augmented,
                steps_per_epoch = nb_test_samples // batch_size,
                epochs = epochs,
                verbose = 1,
                validation_data = valid_generator,
                *validation_steps = nb_val_samples // batch_size*) #Error here
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

I already have the images resized and saved in their respectives directories.

Comment: Please show the whole traceback.  It's not clear how that code could have generated that error.

Comment: what do you think `Dropout(1)` does?

Comment: with dropout=1 all nodes are being dropped!! set it to something like  .2 In the error code it mentions 'rate' so I think it is referring to an invalid dropout rate

Comment: I was using other code as a reference, when can i use dropout = 1 and when i should use 0.2-0.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after setting droput rate 0.2, it started working